# WARNING: Loading FXML document with JavaFX API of version 9 by JavaFX runtime of version 8.0.131

Tags: java, javafx

```
Dec 01, 2017 11:08:16 PM javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ValueElement processValue
WARNING: Loading FXML document with JavaFX API of version 9 by JavaFX runtime of version 8.0.131
```

I got this error even though I just updated my java to the latest version...

Comment: Get Java 9 to fix this problem. If you have it, change your default Java Platform to use it.

Answer (score 2):

I just had to change the version in the xmln attribute of the fxml file.

Answer (score 0):

Add/Edit this xmln attribute to the fxml file:

```
xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/9.0.0"
```